# Combinatorics: fewest weighting possible.

Tags: combinatorics

I have trouble for this weighting problem:

You are given 4 balls, all equal in weight except for one that is either  heavier or lighter. You are also given a two-pan balance to use. In each  use of the balance you may put any number of the 4 balls on the left  pan, and the same number on the right pan, and push a button to initiate  the weighing; there are three possible outcomes: either the weights are  equal, or the balls on the left are heavier, or the balls on the left are  lighter. Your task is to design a strategy to determine which is the odd  ball and whether it is **heavier or lighter** than the others in as **few** uses  of the balance as possible.

My solution is 3 weighting. However, some body told me he can get down to 2 weighting. Can someone please confirm this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two weight is enough. You weight any two balls, by example A and B then you weight another ball, C or D, with A or B.

- if A=B and A=C then D is the different ball
- if A=B and A$\neq$C then C is the different
- if A$\neq$B and A=C then B is the different
- if A$\neq$B and A$\neq$C then A is the different